# elastic search multiple "and" query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

> I want the the result in which query_string '*r*' appear to be in city
>   "BLR"

my query is

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"query_string": {
          "query": "*r*", 
          "fields": [ "name"]
        }}
      ], 
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "city": "BLR"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but expected result are not there. city is a "Text" field. Any idea ??

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442769/search-elasticsearch-field-contained-in-a-value/37678364#37678364

Comment: @Val i am new to elasticsearch. Can you please tell me the solution??

Comment: @Val please can you tell me the solution

Comment: i've checked your query where city is `Keyword` and its worked for me